# Can't download apps from the Google Play store

Tags: google-play-store, google-apps

Whenever I try to download any app from the Google Play store, an error pops up, giving the message "Retrieving information from server. ". This error does not go away, however I try. How do I go about fixing this ?

Comment: Please can you refine your question? it isn't very clear what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! You might wish to take a look at our [google-play-store tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/google-play-store/info), which already holds a list with errors that might occur and the solutions to it. From the phrasing, it looks like we've got that one covered already: [Keep getting “Error retrieving information from server.” from the play store](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/34524/16575)

Comment: Errors present in the Google Play store are not uncommon, and are mostly related to issues with the internet connection, internal storage space, etc. among many factors. So, please mention your device model, Android version and also whether you are rooted or not. Please check for similar questions too, and go through them before posting here. @Izzy mentioned one here, so do go through that. Thanks for using Android Enthusiasts !