# Why my Play Store is not working

Tags: google-play-store

My play store is not working it just say's error while retrieving information [RH-01]

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! If you have issues with Playstore, please take a look at our [google-play-store tag-wiki](/tags/google-play-store/info) where we've collected a list of error messages and linked them to the corresponding posts. For your specific case, that would be: [Keep getting “Error retrieving information from server. `[ RH-01 ]`” from the play store](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/34524/16575). Further it might help to have some more details: device, Android version (custom ROM?), what happened before the issue started (and might have led to it) …

Answer (score 0):

Do this: 
Goto settings-> apps -> play store [Clear cache, clear data, force stop] 
if still doesn't work then try restarting your device.